# How quit form authentication auto redirect

Tags: asp.net

I need for my asp.net aplication not auto-redirect to my web.config login page  when i hit 
Session.abandon() methods.
some ideas? this is my web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Response.Redirect("somePage.aspx")
```

after you do `Session.Abandon()`

[for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)